# What kind of security protocols do current NFC or RFID based technologies use?

Tags: encryption, rfid, nfc

I have an information security class this semester, and I need to write a paper evaluating how secure NFC and RFID technology is.

A lot of questions previously asked here are at least 3 years old, and I'm sure computing power within NFC and RFID tags have increased since then, so I'd like to hear about more recent developments in this area.

I'm aware there are solutions out there for symmetric and asymmetric encryption, but the only problem is, I can't find any good explanations on how they work. Especially the asymmetric solutions.

I would also appreciate it if you could point me to any potential weaknesses within NFC and RFID systems that I could research.

Comment: You've asked a few questions all at once. 1. current state of security protocols, 2. encryption types for different technologies, 3. weaknesses. Please focus the question, and once you do, your research will also be made easier. Like, looking up current security for these things. Also note that RFID and NFC are different technologies with different protocols and capabilities, so you've lumped apples and oranges together and asked about both as if they are the same.

Comment: Related, [Are there any contactless (RFID/NFC) card vulnerabilities that are still unsolved? even minor ones](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/239766/118310)

Comment: Are you proposing I ask all 3 questions separately, or that I should narrow my search as a whole and change this question to match?